# How can I trigger CSS3 transitions on elements appended to the DOM with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I'm building a gantt-chart style schedule view with javascript, and am trying to have my appointments transition in from the left to their *absolutely* positioned *inline* values. I'd like to use CSS3 transitions to handle this.

Individual appointments are added and plotted via javascript and look like this in markup;

```
<div class="appt" style="width: 12.5%; left: 32.5874%;"></div>
```

The .appt class has `-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;` with `top: 0; left: 0` declarations.

I thought that when these appointments were appended to the DOM they'd animate to their inline style positions. How can I do this?

Here is a related, simple, example. http://codepen.io/aaronlsilber/pen/ocqFl

Answer (score 2):

Trigger the CSS transition by setting `left: 0` before appending it, then change the inline css what whatever you want via .css() jQuery function after the append occurs.

Example:

```
$('<div class="appt" style="width: 12.5%; left: 32.5874%;"></div>').appendTo(/*ELEMENT*/);

$('.appt').css('left', '32.5874%');
```

**WARNING**: Not every browser supports CSS transistions (e.g. IE9), if this effect is a must for your user experience I would recommend using jQuery .animate()

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Even better, use [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) which'll use CSS3 when available and fall back to jQuery.animate when it's not.